# How do you query the maximum and minimum length , along with the corresponding string itself?

Tags: sql, mysql

The question is as follows;

*Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
The STATION table is described as follows:*

[image]

*Sample Input*

For example, CITY has four entries: DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY.

*Sample Output*

```
ABC 3
PQRS 4
Explanation
```

*When ordered alphabetically, the CITY names are listed as ABC, DEF, PQRS, and WXY, with lengths 3, 3, 4 and 3 . The longest name is PQRS, but there are 3 options for shortest named city. Choose ABC, because it comes first alphabetically.*

Now to go about this problem, I first queried the MAX and MIN and used the following.

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)), MIN(LENGTH(CITY))
FROM STATION
```

However, the question also asked to query the MAX and MIN string. And I'm not really sure as to how to do it.

Moreover, I also have to make sure, that it is alphabetically organized. I believe I can achieve this using ORDER BY. So, it should look something like this, I guess? I'm not a 100% sure.

```
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)), MIN(LENGTH(CITY))
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY (CITY)
```

**NOTE: I don't have the data. Only the structure. This is a hackerrank problem. Also, I am allowed to write two separate queries to get the desired output.**

Comment: MySql has supported the row_number() window function since version 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to approach this, easiest is to utilize a row number over a window:

```
select city, l
from (
  select city,  Length(city) l,
    Row_Number() over(order by Length(city), city) r1,
    Row_Number() over(order by Length(city) desc, city) r2
  from t
)t
where r1 = 1 or r2 = 1
order by l;
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zma4vOVs)

For older versions you could union two sets

```
select city, l
from (
  select city, Length(city) l
  from t
  order by l, city
  limit 1
)t1
union all
select city, l
from (
  select city, Length(city) l
  from t
  order by l desc, city
  limit 1
)t2
order by l;
```

Comment: Is there a way I could go around solving this using the MAX and MIN functions or is that too complex of a way to approach this problem? Also, is the Row_Number() function an intermediate concept in SQL? I'm yet to study the same.

Comment: hackerrand don't use mysql 8

Comment: @nbk Then how would we go about solving this without the Row_Number() function?

Comment: @tocodeistocreate I don't know anything about Hackerrank but see alternative.